# check condition with userdefaults value exist or not

Tags: swift, ios

I am check first time userDefaults will not save value return 0 else get value from userDefaults

I am checking if `userDefaults` will not save the value, and If it doesn't, return 0. If it does, then I get the value from `userDefaults`.

```
func scaleMeter() {
    let numberPicker = NumberPicker(delegate: self, maxNumber: 100)
    numberPicker.tintColor = .white
    numberPicker.heading = “Select Scale”

    let ageCount = UserDefaults.value(forKey: defaultsKeys.age)
    guard countValue != nil else {
        numberPicker.defaultSelectedNumber = 0
        self.tabBarController?.present(numberPicker, animated: true,  completion: nil)
        return
    }

    numberPicker.defaultSelectedNumber = Int(ageCount as! String)!
    self.tabBarController?.present(numberPicker, animated: true,  completion: nil)

}
```

Is this a correct approach, having `self.tabBarController?.present` both inside and outside the guard?